# ffmpeg recompile video and voice

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing, ubuntu-15.04

I am using Ubuntu vivid on my laptop and I want to recompile audio and voice with delayed audio. Movie was late comparing to audio. I demuxed voice.aac and video.h264 from orginal video. I know that it is possible via editing aac but this file doesnt need any mod for aac. Just wanna delay audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`-itsoffset`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Main-options) option should do what you want:

> -itsoffset offset (input)
>
> Set the input time offset.
>
> offset must be a time duration specification, see [(ffmpeg-utils) the Time duration section in the ffmpeg-utils(1) manual](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax).
>
> The offset is added to the timestamps of the input files. Specifying a positive offset means that the corresponding streams are delayed by the time duration specified in offset.

So

```
$ ffmpeg -i video.h264 -itsoffset 1.0 -i voice.aac -map 0:a -map 1:v -c copy remuxed.mp4
```

should give an audio delay of 1 second. However, **there might be container issues here**, since `ffmpeg` is having to figure everything out from scratch.

What's better is if you **do it using the original file**:

```
 $ ffmpeg -i orig.mkv -itsoffset 1.0 -i orig.mkv -map 0:a -map 1:v -c copy remuxed.mkv
```

This applies a delay of 1 second (*per the option to `-itsoffset`*)  to `input 0`, and no delay to `input 1`. The `-map` options specify to take the (delayed) audio from `input 0` and the (non-delayed) video from `input 1`.

Hope that's clearer!

---

(If you wanted to delay the video instead, change the `-map` options:

```
 $ ffmpeg -i orig.mkv -itsoffset 1.0 -i orig.mkv -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy remuxed.mkv
```

which specifies to take the delayed video, and the non-delayed audio)

Comment: Man this is what I  need. I will try it when I go to home

Comment: Hope it works- I haven't tested. You may need to transcode rather than mux, but hopefully not!

Comment: @makgun I have updated the answer with a better and tested option, assuming you still have the original file :)

Comment: Thanks man this is more usefull than I need to use (at least I think like that) . And map 0:a means that is 0 second delayed Audio? And map 2:v means that is 2 seconds delayed Video?

Comment: @makgun The delay is specified as the option to *-itsoffset*, 1.0 for 1 second, 0.125 for and 8th of a second etc. I have updated the answer to clarify this.

Comment: @bertleb thaks for usefull answer Ive learnt it as well. Now I can watch it without using special video player.

Comment: @bertleb Do you know how can rotate a video x degree (clockwise) I tried ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" out.mp4 . But this option is so slow And then I added -c copy  like ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -cc copy -vf "transpose=1" out.mp4. But again it is so slow. I think it re-encode it. Is there any option to make this fastly?

Comment: Glad you got the answer to work :) Remember you can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the grey tick- no pressure though! About rotating, it is better to ask that as a separate question to avoid extended discussion in comments :)